# OutBound TCP connections are at high spike in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, .net-core-2.0

TCP connections are getting exhausted. Unable to figure out what is the root cause of it. How to figure out common spike issues.

[image]

This is observed after migrating project from .net framework to core 2.0. 
Application downloading blobs using WebClient which is same both in framework and core project.

Comment: You're going to have to do some digging into this issue yourself. Without _any_ context, it's completely impossible for us to be able to help you. Context like: what does the application do, are you building up connections, when does this occur, ...

Comment: This might indicate forgetting to close some connections... For example: have you disposed of all your sql connections? We do need some more context of the application to be fully of help.

Comment: Application downloading blobs using WebClient which is same both in framework and core project.

Answer (score 1):

The outbound TCP connections on the VM instance can be exhausted.

In App Service, limits are enforced for the maximum number of outbound connections that can be made for each VM instance. For more information, reference: Cross-VM numerical limits (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#cross-vm-numerical-limits). You may scale up the App Service Plan as per your requirement.

These limits apply only for customers of Basic or higher plans; in other words, customers running on their own dedicated VMs. These limits are there to protect the entire VM even though one particular site may be with its limits described above. 
The limits are different depending on the size of VM configured.

Limit name  Description Small (A1)  Medium (A2) Large (A3)
Connections Number of connections across entire VM  1920,   3968,   8064 respectively.

Ensure that your application is not trying to access a local address- Connection attempts to local addresses (e.g. localhost, 127.0.0.1) and the machine's own IP will fail, except if another process in the same sandbox has created a listening socket on the destination port.

Reference: http://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/08/starving-outgoing-connections-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ - it’s a 3rd party blog, be cautious with the steps.